# Paramiko channel gets disconnected after executing one command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, channel

I have used Paramiko module to access my server but the problem I am facing is disconnection of channel after executing one command. I want channel to be open, until I finish executing couple of more commands. Running two channel doesn't solve my problem because in first channel I change the directory and wants to run next command in same changed directory.

```
import paramiko


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('xx.xx.xx.xx', username='abc', password='abc')


chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.settimeout(10800)
chan1 = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan1.settimeout(10800)

chan.exec_command('uptime')
chan1.exec_command('who')
data = chan.recv(4096)
print data
data1 = chan1.recv(4096)
print data1
```

Comment: if you're trying to automate remote server commands, you may be happier with [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org), which exposes a higher level API on top of `paramiko`

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko "exec_command" API always open new channel once executed and terminate the channel once command execution completes.

I think you can still have change of one channel command result in second channel command as at last it is on same SSH session. Probably, you may need to add some delay between two command execution. However, if you don't .. don't worry.. there is solution in paramiko to run as many commands

Here is interactive_shell function for paramiko

```
def interactive_shell():
transport = paramiko.Transport(("1.1.1.1",22))
transport.connect(username="abcd", password="abcd")
#chan = paramiko.transport.open_session()
chan = transport.open_session()
chan.setblocking(0)
chan.invoke_shell()
chan.send("uptime")
chan.send("who")
time.sleep(1)  #optional
while not chan.exit_status_ready() :
    if chan.recv_ready() :
        output = chan.recv(8192)
        if len(output) > 0 :
           print output
    if chan.recv_stderr_ready() :
        mystderr = chan.recv_stderr(8192)
        if len(mystderr) > 0 :
            print mystderr

transport.close()
```